# How to retrieve a document from Firestore and assign it to a variable?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

So I want to retrieve a particular Document from a Collection in Firestore and assign the document to a variable so that i can use it in other activity.

Collection contains Users as documents.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Users).document(getCurrentUserID()).get() ....
```

Model class: USER

```
fun getCurrentUserID(): String {
    var currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    var currentUserID = ""
    if (currentUser != null) {
        currentUserID = currentUser.uid
    }
    return currentUserID
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, are you having an error or just don't know how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "assign it to a variable?"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to assign the retrieved user to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your user with using code below, then you can do whatever you want with it.

```
       FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("Users")
            .document(getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                val user = document.toObject(USER::class.java)!!
                // Now we stored information to user variable.
                // You can use it by simply calling user.name etc.
                // If you want to use it out of this block,
                // you need to send it there, example to a function
                deleteUserDetails(user)
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e(
                    this.javaClass.simpleName,
                        "Error while getting user details.",
                        e
                )
            }
       
       fun deleteUserDetails(user: USER) {
          // Now you can use it here too.
          // Example set a textView with user.name or etc.
          textView.text = user.name
       }
```

Comment: But I am not able to access the user variable from outside the addOnSuccessListener{}

Comment: I edited the answer. You need to send it to where you want to use. To a function, fragment or activity, you can choose.